# Auto resize columns based on char count

Tags: .net, vb.net, formatting, reportviewer

I am trying to figure the best way to programmatically re-size table column headers in ReportViewer.

Basically, my current resolution is the following:

```
ColumnWidth = HeaderCaption_CharacterCount * 0.32
```

Where 0.32 is an estimated width of a typical character using my current font size.
The issue is that the width leaves a lot of whitespace for longer captions.  The more characters a caption has, the more whitespace I end up with.

The issue with estimating this way is that not all characters are the same width.  A good example would the the "I" character, which takes up less screen width than the rest of the alphabet.

Can someone suggest a better way to do this?

**EDIT**
I found a better way to handle this.
There is a method that will calculate the width (in pixels) of a string of text.

```
Size = TextRenderer.MeasureText([String], [Font])
```

I am currently experimenting with this,and it looks promising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Size = TextRenderer.MeasureText([String], [Font])`

Function calculates the width of a specified string, with a specified font.